# Why is `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` thrown twice?

Tags: angular

This is my component:

```js
import { AfterViewChecked, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '{{ count }}'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  count = 0;
  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.count++;
  }  
}
```

The website displays '1'. My understanding is that the error is thrown by Angular after the second check because it detects an inconsistent state when the bindings have changed. However the fact that this error is thrown twice implies the change detection cycle is run more than 2 times. But with a console log I can see the `ngAfterViewChecked` is run only 2 times. What am I missing/misunderstanding then? Also, why is the website displaying 1 instead of 0 or 2? `ngAfterViewChecked` is run after `ngAfterViewInit`, and `ngAfterViewInit` is run after the view is initialized. The view should be initialized with `count == 0`, Why is `1` displayed instead? Shouldn't the error be thrown just once?

Answer (score 0):

It is thrown twice because the change detection cycle is run 4 times. In development, every cycle is run twice to make sure the result is consistent. Why Angular goes through this double cycle twice on startup remains a mistery to me.